# JQuery Mobile 1.4 img button in header

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to place a img link in the header but I cant get it to scale correctly. The button is only showing up half the height of the header, and I want the img to scale to the size of the button also. How should I do this?

Also can anyone tell me how I can change the color of the placeholder text of the input when using jquery mobile, the usual solutions dont seem to work when using jquery mobile. Thanks

```
<a href="#" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn"><img id="immo"  class="ui-btn-left" src="http://domaingang.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/example.png"/></a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1gqkon0z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For placeholder css:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}   
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}    
::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}    
:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

For the image button, if you want to use an img element and not set the background image of the button, just set the image size:

```
<a  href="#" data-theme="a" class="imgLink" ><img id="immo"  src="http://domaingang.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/example.png"/></a>

.imgLink {
    padding: 4px 12px;
}
.imgLink img {
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/1gqkon0z/1/)**